# The sum of three exponential function is unsolvable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

$a,b,c,d,f,g$ are parameters. $acf<0$. I tried to solve this:

$ae^{ax+b}+ce^{cx+d}+fe^{fx+g}=0$

But I cannot find any analytical solution. To make things worse, the wolfram alpha solver does not recognize this.

The sum of two exponential functions can be easily solved, though...

I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Why do you expect it to be solvable?

Comment: @WhatsUp Is it possible to prove this or may I find proofs elsewhere?

Comment: Have you thought through how the sum of two exponential functions is solved?  One is put on each side of the equation and then logarithms are taken.  Is there a third side of the equation to put the third exponential function on?

Comment: Let $y = e^{x(c-f)}$ and $p = \frac{a-f}{c-f}$, the equation is equivalent to
$(a e^b) y^p + (c e^d) y + f e^g = 0$. We don't even have elementary solution for polynomial equation of the form $y^p + y + t = 0$ for integer $p \ge 5$. It is unlikely (if not impossible) your equation is solvable when $p$ is a general real number...

Comment: @achillehui Thanks Achille! How do I find a non-elementary solution, then?

Comment: When $p$ is a positive integer, the root can be expressed in terms of [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) which can be further decomposed into a linear combination of hypergeometic functions. I'm not aware
of any elementary or special functions for the general $p$. If you want an expansion, you can always try [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) but I doubt it is practical at all. Finding the root numerically is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ae^{ax+b}+ce^{cx+d}+fe^{fx+g}=0$$
They is a flaw in that question because several parameters are not independent. First the superfluous parameters will be eliminated.
Divide by $fe^{fx+g}$
$$\frac{a}{f}e^{ax+b-fx-g}+\frac{c}{f}e^{cx+d-fx-g}+1=0$$
Let $\quad A=\frac{a}{f}e^{b-g}\quad;\quad B=\frac{c}{f}e^{d-g}\quad;\quad p=a-b\quad;\quad q=d-g$
$$Ae^{px}+Be^{qx}+1=0$$

Change of variable $\quad X=Be^{qx}\quad$ and let $\quad r=\frac{p}{q}\quad,\quad C=AB^{-r}$
$$C\;X^r+X+1=0$$
It is wellknown that the roots of this kind of equation in general cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions.

Of course among the infinity of cases depending on $r$ and $C$ some particular are solvable in terms of elementary functions (for example polynomial equations of degree lower than 5 ) or in terms of special functions (for example polynomial of degree 5 in terms of Jacobi theta functions).

In the general case the roots have to be approximately computed thanks to numerical methods of calculus or on the form of series.